# Apply a function that has arguments from two different dataframes, with group by. (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply, pandas-groupby

I have the following task that troubles me. 
I have a function that I want to apply to a pandas dataframe, by group. This function, takes as input 1 series from another dataframe, and 1 from the current one. I tried many different ways but and eventually I found a solution, however I wonder if there is a better way.

Bellow I provide a reproducible example.

```
#load the data
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
data1 = pd.DataFrame(data= np.c_[ iris['target'], iris['data']],  columns=  ['target'] + iris['feature_names'] )
data2 = pd.DataFrame({'x' : data1[data1.target == 0].iloc[:,1], 'y' :data1[data1.target == 0].iloc[:,2]})

# define one random function
def some_function(x, p):
    err = (x - p )
    return sum(err)
```

So my first try was:

```
data1.groupby('target').apply(lambda x: some_function(data2.iloc[:,0], data1.iloc[:,4])) # this does not work
```

after trying many different ways,

```
 data1.groupby('target').apply(lambda x: some_function(data1.iloc[:,1], data1.iloc[:,4])) # this works
data1.groupby('target').apply(lambda x: some_function(data2.iloc[:,1],data1[data1.target==0].iloc[:,4])) # this works
    data1.groupby('target').apply(lambda x: some_function(data2.iloc[:,1], data1[data1.target==1].iloc[:,4])) # this does not work
```

I found out (after long time) that it was a problem with the indexing. So the following works.

```
data1.groupby('target').apply(lambda x: some_function(data2.iloc[:,0],  x.iloc[:,4].reset_index().iloc[:,1]))
```

Is there any other way? Why if I use `axis = 1` at the end it does not work?

Finally, how can I add this in the new row in the data1? something like that it does not merge the results to all rows.

```
   data1.groupby('target')['new_column'] = data1.groupby('target').apply(lambda x: some_function(data2.iloc[:,0],  x.iloc[:,4].reset_index().iloc[:,1]))
```

or without using the groupby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `reset_index()` with parameter `drop=True` for remove original index values but generally is necessary length of each group is same as length of another DataFrame `data2`:

Test lengths:

```
s1 = data1.groupby('target').size()
print (s1)
target
0.0    50
1.0    50
2.0    50
dtype: int64

print (len(data2))
50
```

---

```
s = (data1.groupby('target')
          .apply(lambda x: some_function(data2.iloc[:,0], 
                                         x.iloc[:,4].reset_index(drop=True))))
```

Alternative is convert `Series` to `numpy array`:

```
s=data1.groupby('target').apply(lambda x: some_function(data2.iloc[:,0],x.iloc[:,4].values))


print (s)
target
0.0    238.1
1.0    184.0
2.0    149.0
dtype: float64
```

And for new column use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
data1['new'] = data1['target'].map(s)
print (data1.head())
   target  sepal length (cm)  sepal width (cm)  petal length (cm)  \
0     0.0                5.1               3.5                1.4   
1     0.0                4.9               3.0                1.4   
2     0.0                4.7               3.2                1.3   
3     0.0                4.6               3.1                1.5   
4     0.0                5.0               3.6                1.4   

   petal width (cm)    new  
0               0.2  238.1  
1               0.2  238.1  
2               0.2  238.1  
3               0.2  238.1  
4               0.2  238.1  

print (data1.tail())
     target  sepal length (cm)  sepal width (cm)  petal length (cm)  \
145     2.0                6.7               3.0                5.2   
146     2.0                6.3               2.5                5.0   
147     2.0                6.5               3.0                5.2   
148     2.0                6.2               3.4                5.4   
149     2.0                5.9               3.0                5.1   

     petal width (cm)    new  
145               2.3  149.0  
146               1.9  149.0  
147               2.0  149.0  
148               2.3  149.0  
149               1.8  149.0
```

Comment: thanks a lot! do you know why I get a warning `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead` when I do the map()?